# Constant derivative of integral expression

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

I work on my assignment and I dont get how the following example works: Let $a \in \mathbb C$, $r > 0$ and $$h(s) = \int_{\lvert a - w \rvert = r} \frac{\mathrm d w}{w - (a + s(z- a))}$$ for $s \in [0,1]$. Here $z$ is such that $B(z, \varepsilon) \subseteq B(a, r)$ for some suitable $\varepsilon > 0$. I want to show that $h$ is constant and therefore I tried to show that $h' = 0$. So one has
$$h'(s) = \int_{\lvert a - w \rvert = r} \frac{\partial}{\partial  s} \bigg(\frac{\mathrm d w}{w - (a + s(z- a))} \bigg) = -\int_{\lvert a - w \rvert = r} \bigg(\frac{(z- a) }{(w - (a + s(z- a)))^2} \bigg) \, \mathrm d w.$$
But I dont see how the last integral is equal to zero. What am I missing?

Comment: What is $z$? ${}{}$

Comment: @Tavish I edited the question.

Comment: It follows from Cauchy's integral formula that $h(s) = 2 \pi i$.

Comment: Try a substitution $u=w-a$